# What is means 32-bit address space

Tags: ip

What is means `32-bit address space` when dealing with IP address spaces?

How can I knowing more about this? Which maths I need to know to understainding this and also subnet masking?

Answer (score 1):

32-bit IP address are for the **Internet Protocol version 4**. I invite you to read the full [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) on IPv4.

In short it's mean that adresses on a IPv4 network are 32 bits long and that you have access to 4 294 967 296‬ (2^32) differents IP adresse. Computer use bits to store numbers and IP are no exception, if you want for more check [binary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

Mask, and submask, are used to indicate wich part of the IP is used for the network and for the host. It's very well explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

All the math behind this are mostly [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), as for the most of computer related stuff.